# jQuery UI dialog standalone/alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to improve the performance of my website. One good axis would be to get rid of the dependency of jQuery UI.

Currently I only need the dialog feature. I thought that I would recode it, but if there is already a similar implementation, it would save me lot of time.

Do you know if there is very similar standalone version of jQuery UI dialog? (basically what I need is to open a centered dialog and load a page in AJAX)

Edit: just to clarify what I'm looking for is a plugin that would have the **same behaviour** as jQuery UI dialog, with something like :

```
$(modale).dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
$(modale).dialog('option', 'width', 'auto');
$(modale).dialog('close');
$(modale).dialog('destroy');
```

Here are the kind of options I use :

```
  var options = {
  width: 500,
  minWidth: false,
  minHeight: false,
  dialogClass: 'modalDefault',
  modal: true,
  closeOnEscape: false,
  open: function(event, ui) {.....},
  close: function() { ......}
  }
```

If you know a plugin that I could integrate as is, or with very little modification, it would be really great. If not possible, I will use custom jquery-ui as suggested by tpaksu

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at below link.

jQuery based simple modal plugin specifically for modal dialogs.

[jQuery Simple Modal Plugin](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

Comment: This one really seems closed to jQuery UI implementation, I'll try it out and tell you how it ends. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use any of the dragging behavior of the jQuery UI dialog boxes then rolling your own lightweight solution (i.e. a centered modal dialog) is straightforward.

You can find a simple implementation here that doesn't rely on any external javascript frameworks: http://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

I use Twitter Bootstrap for the vast majority of my front-end UI controls, but there are couple of blind spots that it doesn't adequately cover, such as date pickers.

Fortunately, the site up at jqueryui.com allows you to download a custom build containing only what you need.  I'd try that out before going for anything new.

Comment: That's what I tried in the first place, but the JS is still about 40kB minified, I think that with optimization, it can be no more than 10kB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [download builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/) to create a customized build of jQuery UI that only includes the widgets that you wish use.

Comment: As stated before, I really want to super-optimize this feature, even with a lightweight build, it is still way behind the minimum possible, as always with frameworks.